# iMessage bubble calling web service freze the view

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

i am using iMessage bubble to create chat view working fine

https://github.com/kerrygrover/iMessageBubble

When i call my web service in my inside method this at end

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
```

here is my web method calling function which gives result out put success and send my chat to the server, but my view freeze.

```
 NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSString *urlString = @"https://url/methodname”;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:employeeId forKey:@"employeeId"];
    [dict setObject:employeename forKey:@"employeename"];
      NSLog(@"dic=%@",dict);
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions     error:&errorReturned];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];


    if (errorReturned)
    {
        //...handle the error

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

        //...do something with the returned value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

plz create a new queue not run this code on main queue . you are running the code on main queue plz use this

```
 dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

        // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
        NSString *urlString = @"https://url/methodname”;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setObject:employeeId forKey:@"employeeId"];
        [dict setObject:employeename forKey:@"employeename"];
          NSLog(@"dic=%@",dict);
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions     error:&errorReturned];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

        NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];


        if (errorReturned)
        {
            //...handle the error

        }
        else
        {
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

            //...do something with the returned value
        }

        });
```